# error when compiling humanoid_localization

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to use humanoid_localization for my autonomous underwater vehicle. However I got the error

```
Could not find module Findoctomap_msgs.cmake or a configuration file for package octomap_msgs
```

while compiling in ROS fuerte, ubuntu 11.04. Could anyone please help me with this error?
Thank you very much.

regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53633/error-when-compiling-humanoid_localization/) by [mihota](https://answers.ros.org/users/3807/mihota/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First question: Are you intentionally using Ubuntu 11.04 with Fuerte, and is 11.04 a requirement? [REP-003](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#fuerte-turtle-mar-2012) states that 11.04 is not a target platform for Fuerte, so you have to compile everything yourself instead of just installing pre-compiled debian packages.

If you check the [humanoid_localization Wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/humanoid_localization), you will see a list of dependencies on the right. These ROS packages are required for compiling humanoid_localization, so you need to find their right source versions (e.g. through the Wiki) and compile them as well. Best check the [humanoid_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/humanoid_navigation?distro=fuerte) stack and install the stacks that it depends on. Now, if you were using Ubuntu 10.04, 11.10, or 12.04 then you could simply install the corresponding debian packages (e.g. `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-octomap-msgs`), otherwise you will have to compile them all from source and add them to your ROS workspace.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0